# Advices needed on ReactiveMongo Insert

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have a Scala class as follows

```
case class Foo(id : String, items : List[Item])

case class Item (name : String)
```

Say I want to add a new item to a mongo collection for a particular `id`. What is the best way to do this?

Currently I have a method to insert new Foo's as follows

```
collection.flatMap(_.insert(foo))
```

But the problem is that if I want to just add another item to a particular foo this does not do this. This only adds a entire foo.

I looked at the documentation and I see that what I want to do, can be achieved with `push`.

I was thinking that I should have some logic in my method so that it does something like this:

```
def insert(foo) = {

//if collection size is zero then
collection.flatMap(_.insert(foo))

//else if collection is not zero use the push method
}
```

I did not want to do an upsert because I think the performance penalty will be high as mongo has to search all items to see if it is there already and then either update or insert. My items will always be unique so it should insert straightaway.

Is there a better way to do this? I am not sure of all of mongo's features.  I am looking for the BEST advices.

Comment: There is nothing specific to ReactiveMongo there, but to MongoDB commands. I suggest to first try in MongoShell, then to code it. BTW `push` is not a command, but either an array operation or an aggregation stage.

Comment: Yes this is good advices